# How to identify connections?

Tags: activemq-artemis

One of the Artemis web console views shows connections. I would like to identify connections. I would like to easily recognize which connection is from which application. I know that I can set **Client ID** but as I understand I have to use JMS API. **Client ID** can be set by calling `org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory#setClientID` method. `ActiveMQConnectionFactory` class is placed in `org.apache.activemq:artemis-jms-client` maven artifact.

Unfortunately I do not use JMS API and I do not want to use it. I use the Artemis core API (`ServerLocator`, `ClientSessionFactory`, `ClientSession` etc from the `org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.client` package). How to identity connections?

Comment: The ActiveMQ Artemis Web Console already shows the username for the connection. Is that not viable for your purpose? If not, why not?

Comment: I think that user is part of Security Domain. I do not use any security now. I do not know Artemis Security but as I understand all users and passwords have to be configured on Artemins  side and each client application has to has its user and password. it's not convenient for me and I do not want to restrict access to artemins. I just want to each client  presents its ID.

Comment: Using an unsecured broker is highly discouraged. Without security any client on the network can do whatever they want with the broker, including shutting it down or deleting messages. For what it's worth, basic security is pretty easy to configure. It just requires editing a few text files. It's also possible to edit the text files at runtime to add users and roles as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way how to set Client ID. It can be set on `org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.client.ClientSession` instance:

```
public static String JMS_SESSION_CLIENT_ID_PROPERTY = "jms-client-id";
...
session.addMetaData(ClientSession.JMS_SESSION_IDENTIFIER_PROPERTY, "");
session.addMetaData(JMS_SESSION_CLIENT_ID_PROPERTY, "myClientID");
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I'd never have thought that something like `session.addMetaData(ClientSession.JMS_SESSION_IDENTIFIER_PROPERTY, "");` could make it work.